# Change index of a word in a label to a different color

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am making a program similar to wordle. Does anybody know how to change just one letter in the label to a different color? For example, making the "f" in "fight" turns red. Thanks.

Comment: Is the string (Flight in your example) fixed or known length?  As far as I can see you’ve got two options.  1) break the word into individual labels for each character, otherwise you could drop the label out of it altogether and just draw directly on the canvas

Comment: Remove the `visual-studio` Tag (unrelated) and add the Tag of the GUI platform you're using (e.g., WinForms, WPF, Xamarin etc.) -- Usually, Labels don't support multiple colors on their own. If the platform is WinForms, you have to paint the Text yourself. Note that you could replace the Label with a read-only RichTextBox, which does support colored selections.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.